# I'm getting the following error when I run my code - TypeError: must be real number, not list

Tags: list, typeerror

This is the problem :

You will be given a list of lists, each sublist will be of length 2 i.e. [[x,y],[p,q],[l,m]..[r,s]] consider its like a martrix of n rows and two columns
a. the first column Y will contain interger values
b. the second column    will be having float values
Your task is to find the value of  (,)=−1∗1Σℎ,(10()+(1−)10(1−))  here n is the number of rows in the matrix
Ex:
[[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
output:
0.4243099
−18⋅((1⋅10(0.4)+0⋅10(0.6))+(0⋅10(0.5)+1⋅10(0.5))+...+(1⋅10(0.8)+0⋅10(0.2)))

My code -

````
def compute_log_loss(A):
    Y = len(A)
    Ys = len(A[0])    
    l = 0

    for i in range(Y):
        for j in range(Ys):
            l += A[i]*math.log10(A[j]) + (1-A[i])*math.log10(1-A[j])
    loss=(-1*l)/Y
    print(loss)
A = [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
compute_log_loss(A)```

Im getting the following error :

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-bd3b5244f95b> in <module>
     17     print(loss)
     18 A = [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
---> 19 compute_log_loss(A)

<ipython-input-97-bd3b5244f95b> in compute_log_loss(A)
     13     for i in range(Y):
     14         for j in range(Ys):
---> 15             l += A[i]*math.log10(A[j]) + (1-A[i])*math.log10(1-A[j])
     16     loss=(-1*l)/Y
     17     print(loss)

TypeError: must be real number, not list
````

Comment: Next time format it as a Python code by specifying the language after those three backticks.
\```python


\```

Answer (score 0):

```
A[i] is a list not an single element.
A = [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1, 0.9], [1, 0.8]]
A[0] =[1, 0.4]
A[0][0] =1
A[0][1] =0.4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.